# Unicode rendering in Web browser as set of question marks

Tags: unicode, webfonts

I have some Sinhala (Indic language) content in a MySQL database and it appears in PHPMyAdmin as given below. It renders in browser fine.

Content in PHPMyAdmin which render correctly in browser:

[image: Content in PHPMyAdmin which render correctly in browser]

Recently I tried to dump another content and it appears in PHPMyAdmin as given below.

Content in PHPMyAdmin which render question marks in browser:

[image: Content in PHPMyAdmin which render question marks in browser]

What is the format I should send the second test to the database to get the first format? Because this renders in the browser as a set of question marks (Eg. ???????).

Comment: The images seem to be the wrong way around. Anyway, we need to see the actual bytes and the HTML encoding. How is the character encoding configured in the database?

Comment: No. This is right, This is how it renders in PHPMyAdmin. But it renders in the web browser properly. How to get the actual bytes?

Comment: See the [Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag wiki](/tags/character-encoding/info) for basic instructions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

Comment: See "question mark" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored